# Index of array exists when logged to console but does not exist when accessed directly

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2-dimensional array that stores "chunks" as canvases in a game. I've encountered a weird problem that seems to have manifested itself seemingly without me changing anything. The range can go negative, so that could be a cause.

When I run a loop to go through and log every index of the array, it only actually logs index -1. When logging the entire 2-dimensional array, indexes -1, 0, and 1 exist. However when I access index 0 of said array it returns `undefined`:

Code used to log array

[image: Code used to log array]

Actual logged results

[image: Logged results]

It's clear that index 0 does exist in the array, but when accessed directly it does not seem to exist and a loop through every index does not think index 0 exists.

This is a pretty bad issue since now the game will re-render a bunch of canvases, killing fps, and making the game unplayable. I don't know why this is happening, and I really have no idea why this is happening. This wasn't happening before and I haven't touched the code, but I discovered my fps was dying and eventually found that the cause was the continuous re-rendering of chunks that already existed.

I've tried a few things, including:

- Changing all array indexes to integers with `parseInt()`
- Trying to access the index as a string
- Removing all other code that manipulates the MAPS variable

It doesn't seem to be easily reproducible since I don't know the cause, but I will try and find the exact reason why it seems to do this.

Update: It seems to work when directly accessed through console, however in the function it doesn't work.

[image: UPdate]

Ignore the two logs between the entry and the output, that's caused by a bit of lag.

Update 2: The length of the array appears to be negative, though it still has positive indexes.

[image: update2]

Update 3: I just checked GitHub Desktop and I have not changed anything related to the array, and it does not happen on the older code. I don't know what could have made this suddenly happen.

Comment: The console keeps a live reference to the array. So if the array is modified after you log it, you'll see the new indexes when you expand it, even if they weren't there when you tried to log that index.

Comment: Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(array))` to see a snapshot of the array at that time.

Comment: Note that array indexes are non-negative indexes. You can add other properties to the array, but they won't be shown by `JSON.stringify()`. Use an object if you need more general properties.

Comment: @Barmar I removed all code that would clear or remove indexes from the array and it still logged `undefined` for index 0. That doesn't seem to be the issue and JSON.stringify just deletes the array.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: It works when logging with the console, but in code it doesn't. I may have made a bad typo somewhere.

Comment: That will also make a snapshot of the array.

Comment: It appears that the length of the array is displayed as negative, which is strange considering there are also positive numbers as indexes. See attached screenshot in update 2

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the "handy trick" to clearing an array does not work - setting the length of an array to 0 does not always clear it. It ends up doing something and does not seem to work correctly in my case.

Also it turns out I was accidentally clearing portions of the array.

Sorry.